# Check if a user has a specific object with quick.db

Tags: node.js, discord.js, quick.db

Hello I am trying to check if someone has an object in his inventory witch quick.db
But when I try, whatever the artist is it always says that it's the inventory of the user. Here's the code that I use.

```js
const db = require('quick.db');
let discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name : 'test',
    description : "commande test",
    async execute(message, args) {

        const artist = message.content.slice(7).trim();

        if(!artist){
            message.channel.send("Spécifier l'artiste")
        }



        if(db.has(message.author.id, artist)){
            message.channel.send("Artiste Present")
        }
        else{
            message.channel.send("Non présent")
        }


    }

}
```

I use this to add information to the database

```js
if (reaction.count == 2){
   db.push(user.id, name_artist);
```

Comment: According to quick.db [docs](https://quickdb.js.org/overview/docs#has) and [source code](https://github.com/lorencerri/quick.db/blob/master/src/methods/has.js). The second argument of `.has()` method should be object instead of string.

Comment: and how can i define my string as an object

Comment: Could you provide us the code where you actually add these into the database. Without this we can't really provide you with an accurate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are only checking if the database has a specific user id as a key. According to the quick.db [docs](https://quickdb.js.org/overview/docs#push).

To check if an artist is stored in an array I would try this.

```js
if (db.get(message.author.id).includes(artist)) {
    message.channel.send("Artiste Present")
}
else {
    message.channel.send("Non présent")
}
```